# File System is corrupt Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, corruption

I keep recieveing an "The file system is corrupt" error on a new Dell powerEdge T430 Server running windows server 2012 r2. I am running in a RAID 5 config with 3 Kingston 960 GB Enterprise SSD's. I have run tests on the disk and they come out good, along with updating the controller software and I still get the error. Has anyone else ever ran into this problem?

Comment: `1.` Are those drives supported in the server? `2.` If this is a new server then I'd suggest that you open a support ticket with Dell.

Comment: `3.` If the server is not new but you have an extended warranty contract, open a support ticket with Dell. `4.` If not, where exactly do you read that error message? Please provide *all* information regarding the error. For what it's worth, you could be infected by malware trying to get you to buy certain "software" that fixes your problem ;)

Comment: The drives are supported by the server but not by Dell so a support ticket would do no good. The file system is corrupt error is coming back in our RMM (AVG managed workplace) not on the actual server itself.